# How to use an Apex scheduler to send periodic emails with the pdf file as attachment?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, scheduled-apex, apex-email-service

I have created one vf page to create a report on what are the open cases available in the particular org as a PDF. I need to use an Apex schedular to send periodic emails with the pdf file as attachment to my client email id.

Can you please any one help me on this?

I have given below the vf page and Apex class which I used for creating report as a PDF.

VF Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock >

    {!contactName}'s Cases

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c">    

        <apex:column value="{!c.status}"/>

        <apex:column value="{!c.subject}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class retrieveCase {

    public String getContactName() {
        return 'Babara Levy';
    }

    public List<Case> getCases() {
        return [SELECT status, subject FROM Case
                WHERE Contact.name = 'Babara Levy' AND status != 'Closed' limit 5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to create a VF email template, since you cant use getContentAsPDF in an async context.

have a look into the documentation
**Creating Visualforce Email Templates**
http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_visualforce_email_templates.htm

**Integrating Email with Visualforce**
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_and_templates.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try these links and update you on the same